# Fluent NHibernate Uni-Directional one to one mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-one

I cant get at [One-to-One](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/19/nhibernate-mapping-lt-one-to-one-gt.aspx) relationship working with Fluent NHibernate. I have  User and UserDetails tables and they 'share' a primary key. How do I map them?

This is my latest/best attempt, this fails with *NHibernate.Id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property: User*

**User**

```
 protected UserMap()
{
        Table("user");
        Id(x => x.Id)
        .Column("user_key")
       .GeneratedBy.GuidComb().UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty);

         References(x => x.UserDetail)
        .PropertyRef(x=>x.User)
        .Column("user_key")
        .Not.Insert().Not.Update().Cascade.All();

}
```

**UserDetail**

```
protected UserDetailMap()
{
     Table("user_detail");
     Id(x => x.Id).Column("user_key")
        .GeneratedBy.Foreign("User")
        .UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty);

     References(x => x.User)
        .Column("user_key")
        .Not.Insert().Not.Update().Unique().Cascade.None();

}
```

Comment: Dan, did you ever get this to work?  The issue you had looks exactly the same as the one I'm having.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
protected UserDetailMap()
{
    Table("user_detail");
    Id(x => x.Id)
       .Column("user_key")
       .GeneratedBy.Foreign("User")
       .UnsavedValue(Guid.Empty);

    HasOne(x => x.User)
       .Constrained();    
}
```

Comment: That creates the exception - NHibernate.Id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property: User

Comment: Are reference set? You should manually set references `user.Details = details; details.User = user;`